# What is the !=~ comparison operator in ruby?

Tags: ruby, operators

I found this operator by chance:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :028 > "abc" !=~ /abc/
 => true
```

what's this? It's behavior doesn't look like "not match".

Comment: Doesn't seem to be a real operator. most likely it's `!`  and `=~`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

That's not one operator, that's two operators written to look like one operator.

From the [operator precedence table](http://phrogz.net/programmingruby/language.html#table_18.4) (highest to lowest):

> `[] []=`
>   `**`
>   `! ~ + -` *[unary]*
>   *[several more lines]*
>   `<=> == === != =~ !~`

Also, the Regexp class has a [unary `~` operator](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Regexp.html#method-i-~):

> **~ rxp → integer or nil**
>   Match—Matches `rxp` against the contents of `$_`. Equivalent to `rxp =~ $_`.

So your expression is equivalent to:

```
"abc" != (/abc/ =~ $_)
```

And the [`Regexp#=~`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Regexp.html#method-i-3D~) operator (not the same as the more familiar [`String#=~`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-3D~)) returns a number:

> **rxp =~ str → integer or nil**
>   Match—Matches rxp against str.

So you get true as your final result because comparing a string to a number is false.

For example:

```
>> $_ = 'Where is pancakes house?'
=> "Where is pancakes house?"
>> 9 !=~ /pancakes/
=> false
>> ~ /pancakes/
=> 9
```

Answer (score 20):

`!~` is the inverse of `=~` NOT `!=~`