# Operator !=~ in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Here is a code used to display error messages

```
ActionView::Base.field_error_proc = Proc.new do |html_tag, instance_tag|
  unless html_tag =~ /^<label/
    "<span class=\"field_with_errors\">#{html_tag}</span>".html_safe
  else
    "#{html_tag}".html_safe
  end
end
```

However, it's better to not use `unless` and `else` together. So I did

```
ActionView::Base.field_error_proc = Proc.new do |html_tag, instance_tag|
  if html_tag !=~ /^<label/
    "#{html_tag}".html_safe
  else
    "<span class=\"field_with_errors\">#{html_tag}</span>".html_safe 
  end
end
```

and it's not working.

I know this is because of `"!=~"`. 
Well, how do I change it to make it work?

Comment: what wrong with `unless` though I dont understand why people dont use `unless` as effective as `if` well you can use `not` though preceded by `if` something like `not(html_tag =~ /^<label/)` hope this help

Comment: The operator is `!~`, but then you wouldn't want to switch the operations done in the block.

Comment: Semi duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/7693486/479863

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should just use `=~`. The following gives the same result as your original code with `unless`:

```
ActionView::Base.field_error_proc = Proc.new do |html_tag, instance_tag|
  if html_tag =~ /^<label/
    "#{html_tag}".html_safe
  else
    "<span class=\"field_with_errors\">#{html_tag}</span>".html_safe 
  end
end
```

Comment: Then I don't understand why is it working? Why `unless html_tag =~ /^<label/` is equal to `if html_tag =~ /^<label/`?

Comment: No. It's the opposite, but your `else` clause in the original is now in the `if` and vice versa. That's why it works.

Answer (score 4):

`!=~` isn't a Ruby operator, so it actually tokenizes as `!= ~`, which is an entirely different operation. Thus, `html_tag !=~ /^<label/` actually tests `html_tag != ~/^<label/`, which is equal to `html_tag != nil`, which will always be true.

You can see this here:

```
>> "x" !=~ nil
NoMethodError: undefined method `~' for nil:NilClass
    from (irb):104
    from :0
```

You should just use plain `=~`.

Answer (score 3):

The alternative solution to the above is to use the !~ operator, which is the inverse of =~.