# What is the meaning of operator ==~ in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, operators

I am modifying an existing ruby code. It has the following lines of code. Can somebody tell me what is going on.

```
if string ==~ /^ABC/
     do-something
elsif string == "some string"
     do-something
else
     do-something
end
```

What is the if condition doing here. I googled for **==~** operator and found nothing.
I just found explanation for **=~**, which means matching strings with regular expressions.
So, if the above if condition has single = , it means check if string starts with ABC. But that is not happening when i run the code. Even though string starts with ABC, it doesn't go into if.

I am not sure if it is a mistake or intentional usage of **==~**

Comment: I'm guessing it's a typo. It's not something I've seen before, maybe someone else has, but it's also not [in the source](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/master/parse.y#L1195-L1217).

Comment: You could define it as a method if you chose, but it’s not a core method, keyword, or operator.

Comment: @anothermh `!=~` isn't an operator either but [`"abc" !=~ /abc/`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7693486/479863) is syntactically valid code. But yeah, it is almost certainly a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unary `~` operator has higher precedence than `==` or `=~` so this:

```
string ==~ /^ABC/
```

is just a confusing way of writing:

```
string == (~/^ABC/)
```

But what does [`Regexp#~`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Regexp.html#method-i-7E) do? The fine manual says:

> **~ rxp → integer or nil**
> Match—Matches rxp against the contents of `$_`. Equivalent to `rxp =~ $_`.

and [`$_`](https://ruby-doc.com/core/doc/globals_rdoc.html) is "The last input line of string by gets or readline." That gives us:

```
string == (/^ABC/ =~ $_)
```

and that doesn't make any sense at all because the right hand side will be a number or `nil` and the left hand side is, presumably, a string. The condition will only be true if `string.nil?` and the regex match fails but there are better ways to doing that.

I think you have two problems:

1. `==~` is a typo that should probably be `=~`.
2. Your test suite has holes, possibly one hole that the entire code base fits in.

---

See also [**What is the !=~ comparison operator in ruby?**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7693486/479863) for a similar question.

Comment: you are right. else is my typo. it is elsif and not else. will modify the question.